# Can't keep keyboard layout on Garuda dragonized

Tags: arch-linux, kde, wayland

I just installed Garuda dragonized and I'm using the wayland session:

```
OS: Garuda Linux x86_64
Host: MS-7C37 1.0
Kernel: 6.6.2-zen1-1-zen
```

But i don't understand why, when i boot, i have this error message:

```
Fcitx should be launched by KWin under KDE Wayland in order to use Wayland input method frontend
```

And even if i do what's asking : go to virtual keyboard and set to fcitx5; i just got another error saying to not set GTK_IM_MODULE and QT_IM_MODULE. And the french keyboard layout disappeared. Like i said, i'm on a fresh garuda setup.But i also tried to follow this and add this environment variable:

```
XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
```

Without any result.Do you have any idea of what i could miss?